# How to update the data table on client side.(iOS MMO game)

Tags: ios, client

Currently I'm developing an iOS MMO game using cocos2d-x. The game uses many data tables (excel files) which are created by the designer. These tables contains such numbers as how much gold(crystal, etc..) will be needed for upgrading a barrack.

My question is, is that how to update that tables once if the tables have been modified on the server side?

My option: Use SQLite to store table on client side, once the tables has been modified on server side, the server will parse the tables (excel files) and send the data in JSON format.
then the client parse the JSON string and save that data to SQLite file.
Is there any better way?  I find that some game stores CSV files on client side, how do they update those CSV files?

Answer (score 0):

How you store the data (and in which format) is entirely up to you, although the framework does provide some helper classes (checkout ccUserDefault).  The simplest way to check whethere data files on the client side are up to date is to checksum them (either apply a checksum to the data stored in the file or on the whole file itself).  So to check for sync, the server side app applies a checksum to the data and so does the client (using the same algorithm, of course ;) ) and the numbers are compared; if they match, the data is in sync.

This is arguably more reliable if the server-side app generates the data files and sends them down, rather than relying on the client-side app to do it.  But as long as the server knows how to generate data files using the same method that the client does, then the success of the client's file generation process can always be verified using this same checksum method.